# Using zoomToEnvelope in webmap?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-online, arcgis-ios

I am working on an app that displays a map. I have the code opening the webMap I have on ArcGIS.com.

In the method

```
-(void)webMapDidLoad:(AGSWebMap *)webMap
```

I set an envelope and then call

```
[self.mapView zoomToEnvelope:env animated:YES];
```

But the map just zooms to its normal extent, rather than the one I specified. I can't quite  figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: To try and progress this would you be able to provide a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck, please?  At the moment you are talking about code rather than presenting a code snippet.